# Is there a verb phrase for not working on a Monday or a Friday so as to have a four-day weekend?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

I don't mean having a long weekend due to a holiday falling on a Friday or a Monday. I mean when the holiday falls on a Tuesday or a Thursday (Thanksgiving in the US for instance) I'm looking for **a verb phrase** for "not working on what would be a normal working day, so as to have a four-day weekend, and **a noun** for that specific day. It may be that all employees are given that benefit or that some of them simply decide to make that Monday or Friday a non-working day on their own.

- The French say "faire le pont" (to make a bridge)
- In some Spanish speaking countries it's "hacer un día puente", "San Lunes", or "San Viernes" (Saint Monday, Saint Friday)
- In Chile some people say "tomarse el sandwich" (to make a sandwich)
- Brazilians say "enforcar a sexta-feira or segunda-feira" (a hanged Friday or a hanged Monday.)
- In Germany, the word "Brückentag" is used.

I'm not looking for "extended weekend", "Bank Holiday weekend" or "long weekend".  I'm looking for **a noun phrase** for the Monday or Friday sandwiched between the weekend and the Tuesday or Thursday (e.g. "Brückentag" in German), and **a verb phrase** for not working on those days ("faire le pont" in French, or "enforcar a segunda-feira" in Portuguese.

Comment: I’ve always wondered why English doesn’t have a standard phrase for this common situation, particularly now in mid-November given that the American Thanksgiving holiday is statutorily set to be the fourth Thursday in November, leaving the day following a good choice to take off. It’s also one of the few floating federal holidays remaining to us, after the [Uniform Monday Holiday Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Monday_Holiday_Act).  By the way, *hacer un puente* in Spanish can also mean “jumping” one’s dead car battery to restart it using jumper cables in an appropriate context.

Comment: The Uniform Monday Holiday Act was allegedly created so federal workers would never “lose” a floating holiday that fell on the weekend instead of during the workweek, but it also cuts out the equally likely case of it falling on Tuesday or Thursday with that occasion’s tacit invitation for employees to skip work by feigning illness or taking a personal vacation day. Now there’s no risk of that and so overall “productivity” is “better”. Longer, more “exotic” bridge days (ES: *macropuentes*) [remain controversial](http://economia.elpais.com/economia/2015/10/18/actualidad/1445184098_938238.html).

Comment: English does have a common phrase: to take a long weekend (which can be three or four days). ***It's just not sexy***. I really do not understand all this fuss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convey  the idea of a "bridge" in English you world usually refer to a "***four/five-day weekend"***  accordiny  to how many day are involved in the holiday. It is an extension of the common  concept of [long weekend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_weekend).

> - ***A long weekend is a weekend that is at least three days long*** (so, a three-day weekend), due to a holiday falling on either the Friday or Monday.
> - ***Most countries also feature many four-day weekends, in which two days adjoining the weekend are holidays***. (Examples can include Easter Monday / Good Friday, and Christmas Day / Boxing Day.)
> - Further, in many nations, when a lone holiday occurs on a Tuesday or a Thursday, the gap between that day and the weekend may also be designated as a holiday, or set to be a movable or floating holiday, or indeed work/school may be avoided by consensus unofficially. ***This is typically referred to by a phrase involving "bridge" in most languages.***
> - A special situation exists in France in some elementary schools, where there is no school on Wednesday: thus, any four-day weekend is essentially a "five-day weekend" for the kids and their teachers. ***Any four-day bridge, for example: Thursday (Holiday) and Friday (bridge day) for Ascension, is essentially a "five-day weekend" to some teachers.***

Wikipedia

Comment: I’m not convinced that making a long weekend out of it is a good match for this concept. Holidays falling on Friday or Monday already make for a long weekend, so when the holiday falls on Thursday or Tuesday and the employee takes (or is given) the intervening non-holiday workday as a bridge between the holiday and the weekend, also calling that a long weekend seems to efface the special character of taking that “bridge day” off.

Comment: @tchrist- the expression I am suggesting is not "long weekend", as I said the expression one would use is "four/five-day weekend" according to how many days are  involved. In other languages you would also say a "four/five-day bridge".

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. It looks like [the Italian designation of *ponte*](http://www.giornalettismo.com/archives/1921671/ponti-festivita-2016-calendario/) also(?) applies to a holiday falling on Mon/Fri, creating in effect a “three-day weekend” without having to bridge any gap. Is there a distinction in Italy for when the holiday falls on Tue/Thu so there’s an intervening *giorno lavorativo* that people arrange not to work on? I see you can also have [*un maxi-ponte*](http://www.lastampa.it/2015/12/08/italia/politica/il-maxiponte-in-parlamento-fRFvnt87tWzaBfwJzBuoPP/pagina.html) for a longer break.

Comment: @tchrist - I changed my introductory notes, hope it is clear now. The example you make is that of a typical bridge where you usually have a working day just before or after the weekend.

Comment: I think most phrases involving bridging or bridge(ing) days should be perfectly understandable, grammatically, but is the real object precision or poetry?

“Long weekend” already covers Friday to Sunday, Saturday to Monday and Friday to Monday with no way to tell which. What does a five-day weekend really specify?

When does “a bridge to Tuesday” or “a bridging day on Monday” start? Is it tied to Saturday or might it run from Friday?

If it reaches right back to Thursday do those six days now make a short week, or what?

Comment: make a long weekend out of it no: to take a long weekend. In English, a long weekend can be three or four days. Bridges are out in regular English.